# div not positioning correctly in chrome and safari

Tags: html, css

I have this page...http://thornwoodfinehomes.com/whatsNew.php and it looks good in Firefox and IE 7,8 & 9 but not in Safari and Google Chrome.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="contentAreaAvailable">
<div class="content">
<div class="contentText">
Some Text
<img src="pics/whatsNew1.jpg" width="407" height="247" border="0" />
</div><!--contentText-->

<div class="rightContent">
<img src="pics/whatsNew2.jpg" width="332" border="0" />
<br /><br />
<img src="pics/whatsNew3.jpg" width="332" border="0" />
</div><!--rightContent-->

</div><!--content-->
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%; float:left; padding-top:15px; font-size:26px;">
<stong><em>Coming soon, some exciting opportunities in Roseland Burlington.</em></stong>
</div>

</div><!--contentAreaAvailable-->
```

And here is the CSS

```
.contentAreaAvailable{
    background:#000;
    padding:50px;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    width:912px;
    height:730px;
    float:left;
}

.content{
    padding-bottom:4px;
}

.contentAvailable{
    /*padding:20px 0 0 0;*/
    width:566px;
    font-size:22px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}

.rightContentAvailable{
    float:right;
}
```

I have no idea why its doing this in chrome and safari, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: .contentavailable { width: 560px; } and it's fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're setting the widths, but it seems the left div *contentAvailable* is a little bit too big.  When I resized it from 566px down to 500px, the right div *rightContentAvailable* slid up, and the layout looked normal.  (This was in Chrome.)

Also, using the developer tools in Chrome is a good way to troubleshoot layout issues.